# Find nodes with the same couple of attributes with xslt and add a new node

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I need to analyse the following XML input:

```
<LIST>

    <PRODUCT TYPE="1" REP="0">
        <SUB CAT="1.1" COUNT="2">


            <ITEM  NAME="OCC" BEGIN="0" ND="49">

            </ITEM>


            <ITEM NAME="OCC"  BEGIN="0" END="49">

            </ITEM>

        </SUB>
    </PRODUCT>

    <PRODUCT TYPE="1" REP="1">
        <SUB CAT="1.1" COUNT="1">

            <ITEM  NAME="PRC" BEGIN="0" END="49">

            </ITEM>
        </SUB>
    </PRODUCT>

</LIST>
```

and transform it with Xslt to obtain the following result:

```
<LIST>

    <PRODUCT TYPE="1" REP="0">
        <SUB CAT="1.1" COUNT="2">

            <MULTIPLE />
            <ITEM  NAME="OCC" BEGIN="0" END="49">

            </ITEM>

            <MULTIPLE />
            <ITEM NAME="OCC"  BEGIN="0" END="49">

            </ITEM>

        </SUB>
    </PRODUCT>

    <PRODUCT TYPE="1" REP="1">
        <SUB CAT="1.1" COUNT="1">
            <MULTIPLE />
            <ITEM  NAME="PRC" BEGIN="0" END="49">

            </ITEM>
        </SUB>
    </PRODUCT>

</LIST>
```

What I need to do is to check that the BEGIN and END of the ITEMS in two different PRODUCT node are the same, and if this is the case add the MULTIPLE node as a flag. 
Any idea on how to proceed?
This is how I thought it could work:

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


<xsl:template match="//PRODUCT[@TYPE='1']/SUB[@CAT='1.1']/ITEM">
  
  
<xsl:if test="//PRODUCT[@TYPE='1']/SUB[@CAT='1.1']/ITEM /RULE (@BEGIN &lt;= current()/@BEGIN) and (@END &gt;= current()/@END)]">

   
  <xsl:element name="MULTIPLE">
          
  </xsl:element> 

   
  </xsl:if>

    
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by means of a key to look up `ITEM` elements

```
<xsl:key name="item" match="ITEM" use="concat(@BEGIN, '|', @END)" />
```

Then, you just need a template that matches `ITEM` elements where there is at least 2 items in the key

```
<xsl:template match="ITEM[key('item', concat(@BEGIN, '|', @END))[2]]">
```

Using this in conjunction with the XSLT identity transform, gives you this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:key name="item" match="ITEM" use="concat(@BEGIN, '|', @END)" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ITEM[key('item', concat(@BEGIN, '|', @END))[2]]">
    <MULTIPLE />
    <xsl:call-template name="identity" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you wish to restrict it to look for matches in the same product and sub-category, change the key to this...

```
<xsl:key name="item" match="ITEM" use="concat(../../@TYPE, '|', ../@CAT, '|', @BEGIN, '|', @END)" />
```

And adjust the template match accordingly....

```
<xsl:template match="ITEM[key('item', concat(../../@TYPE, '|', ../@CAT, '|', @BEGIN, '|', @END))[2]]">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this way by match the ITEM context:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ITEM">
        <xsl:if test="(
            (@BEGIN = ancestor::PRODUCT/following-sibling::PRODUCT/descendant::ITEM/@BEGIN) and 
            (@END = ancestor::PRODUCT/following-sibling::PRODUCT/descendant::ITEM/@END))
             or (
            (@BEGIN = ancestor::PRODUCT/preceding-sibling::PRODUCT/descendant::ITEM/@BEGIN) and 
            (@END = ancestor::PRODUCT/preceding-sibling::PRODUCT/descendant::ITEM/@END)
            )
            ">
        <xsl:element name="MULTIPLE"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```