# How to match nodes with common attributes and different ones with xslt

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I Have an XML file like the one below. What I need to do is to add a Flag to each `<TOKEN>` node with a `<MULTIPLE TYPE='YES'>` node when:

1. there exist more than one `<TOKEN>` with the same `@BEGIN-@END`
2. at least one of the `<TOKEN> @TEXT` is different from the others with the same`@BEGIN-@END`

The xml code is the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ALL>
        <RECORD TEMPLATE="PRODUCTS" DB="0">
            <FIELD NAME="PRODUCT" BASE="AST" >          
                <TOKEN  TEXT="AST" BEGIN="0" END="100"/>
            </FIELD>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD TEMPLATE="PRODUCTS" DB="1" >
            <FIELD NAME="PRODUCT" BASE="BUC" >
                <TOKEN TEXT="BUC" BEGIN="0" END="100"/>
                <TOKEN TEXT="BUC" BEGIN="0" END="100"/>
                <TOKEN TEXT="BUC" BEGIN="0" END="100"/>
                <TOKEN TEXT="BUC" BEGIN="0" END="100"/>
                <TOKEN TEXT="BUC" BEGIN="102" END="133"/>
                <TOKEN TEXT="BUC" BEGIN="102" END="133"/>
            </FIELD>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD TEMPLATE="PRODUCTS" DB="1" >
            <FIELD NAME="PRODUCT" BASE="BUC" >
                <TOKEN TEXT="ART" BEGIN="300" END="450"/>
                <TOKEN TEXT="ART" BEGIN="300" END="450"/>
            </FIELD>
        </RECORD>

    </ALL>
```

The desired output is the following:

```
<ALL>
    <RECORD DB="0" TEMPLATE="PRODUCTS">
        <FIELD BASE="AST" NAME="PRODUCT">           
             <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES"/>
             <TOKEN BEGIN="0" END="100" TEXT="AST"/>
        </FIELD>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD DB="1" TEMPLATE="PRODUCTS">
        <FIELD BASE="BUC" NAME="PRODUCT">
            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES"/>
            <TOKEN BEGIN="0" END="100" TEXT="BUC"/>

            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES"/>
            <TOKEN BEGIN="0" END="100" TEXT="BUC"/>

            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES"/>
            <TOKEN BEGIN="0" END="100" TEXT="BUC"/>

            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES"/>
            <TOKEN BEGIN="0" END="100" TEXT="BUC"/>

            <TOKEN BEGIN="102" END="133" TEXT="BUC"/>

            <TOKEN BEGIN="102" END="133" TEXT="BUC"/>
        </FIELD>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD DB="1" TEMPLATE="PRODUCTS">
        <FIELD BASE="BUC" NAME="PRODUCT">

            <TOKEN BEGIN="300" END="450" TEXT="ART"/>

            <TOKEN BEGIN="300" END="450" TEXT="ART"/>
        </FIELD>
    </RECORD>
</ALL>
```

I tried using the following xslt, and try to match either the `@BEGIN-@END` and the `@TEXT`, but it didn't work.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                        
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" cdata-section-elements="DOCUMENT" method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" />

          <xsl:key name="token" match="//RECORD[@TEMPLATE='PRODUCTS']/FIELD[@NAME='PRODUCT']/TOKEN" use="concat(@BEGIN, '|', @END)"/>
          <xsl:key name="text" match="//RECORD[@TEMPLATE='PRODUCTS']/FIELD[@NAME='PRODUCT']/TOKEN" use="@TEXT"/>

      <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="//RECORD[@TEMPLATE='PRODUCTS']/FIELD[@NAME='PRODUCT']/TOKEN  [key('token', concat(@BEGIN, '|', @END))[2]] [(key('word', @TEXT)[2])] ">
        <xsl:element name="MULTIPLE">
            <xsl:attribute name="TYPE">YES</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>  
        <xsl:call-template name="identity" />
      </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Removing form the xslt above the `[(key('word', @TEXT)[2])]` part of code, the `<MULTIPLE TYPE='YES'>` node is added, but on every `<TOKEN>` with the same `@BEGIN-@END`, not checking if exists a `@TEXT` node different from the others.

Comment: Please see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48720318/find-nodes-with-the-same-couple-of-attributes-with-xslt-and-add-a-new-node/48720594#48720594

Comment: Thank you for pointing me out this previous question. Unfortunately the problem with these solutions is that they only check if nodes have the same  `@BEGIN-@END`, and apply the `<MULTIPLE>` flag to all of them. I need another condition that blocks the  `<MULTIPLE>` flag to be assigned if all the tokens with the same  `@BEGIN-@END` also have the same `@TEXT` attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                        
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="TOKEN">
        <xsl:variable name="current" select="concat(@BEGIN,@END)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="text" select="@TEXT"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::RECORD/following-sibling::RECORD/FIELD/TOKEN|ancestor::RECORD/preceding-sibling::RECORD/FIELD/TOKEN">
            <xsl:if test="(concat(@BEGIN,@END) = $current) and (@TEXT!=$text)">
                <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <TOKEN>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </TOKEN>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```